# How to insert a new row into a range and copy formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I have a named range like the following covering A2:D3

```
ITEM    PRICE   QTY SUBTOTAL
1           10  3   30
1           5   2   10
           TOTAL:   40
```

I am to insert a new row using VBA into the range copying the formulas not values.

Any tips/links greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it matter which row you copy from?  I assume if we insert the row immediately before the total and use the formulae from the row above, that would work for you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Private Sub newRow(Optional line As Integer = -1)
Dim target As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim rowNr As Integer

    Set target = Range("A2:D3")

    If line <> -1 Then
        rowNr = line
    Else
        rowNr = target.Rows.Count
    End If

    target.Rows(rowNr + 1).Insert
    target.Rows(rowNr).Copy target.Rows(rowNr + 1)
    For Each cell In target.Rows(rowNr + 1).Cells
        If Left(cell.Formula, 1) <> "=" Then cell.Clear
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `target.Rows(rowNr + 1).Insert`: 1) does not extend the Named Range by one Row (AFAIK the only way to do so implicitly via Insert Row (vs. explicitly modifying Range definition) and to do so *after* specified Row # is via Row #'s 1 to Count - 1) and 2) only shifts Columns in the `target` Range down by one Row.  In many (and probably most) cases, Columns to the right and/or left of the `target` Range need to be shifted down as well.  3) `target.Rows(rowNr).Copy target.Rows(rowNr + 1)` does not copy the Formats which are often if not usually desired also.  See my alternate Answer below.

Answer (score 4):

If you start recording a macro and actually do the task in hand, it will generate the code for you.  Once finished, stop recording the macro and you'll have the code needed which you can then amend.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you: http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/insrtrow.htm

Answer (score 1):

I needed to roll a solution that worked like the way a data connection query expands a result-range with optionally autofilling formulas off to the right. Perhaps two years late for the bounty, but I'm happy to share anyway!

```
Public Sub RangeExpand(rangeToExpand As Range, expandAfterLine As Integer, Optional linesToInsert As Integer = 1, Optional stuffOnTheRight As Boolean = False)
    Debug.Assert rangeToExpand.Rows.Count > 1
    Debug.Assert expandAfterLine < rangeToExpand.Rows.Count
    Debug.Assert expandAfterLine > 0

    If linesToInsert = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Assert linesToInsert > 0

    Do
        rangeToExpand.EntireRow(expandAfterLine + 1).Insert
        linesToInsert = linesToInsert - 1
    Loop Until linesToInsert <= 0

    If stuffOnTheRight Then
        rangeToExpand.Item(expandAfterLine, rangeToExpand.Columns.Count + 1).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(rangeToExpand.Item(expandAfterLine, 1), Selection).Select
    Else
        Range(rangeToExpand.Item(expandAfterLine, 1), rangeToExpand.Item(expandAfterLine, rangeToExpand.Columns.Count)).Select
    End If
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(rangeToExpand.Item(expandAfterLine, 1), rangeToExpand.Item(rangeToExpand.Rows.Count, Selection.Columns.Count))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This Answer addresses the following 3 issues with the currently Accepted Answer from @marg originally posted Apr 13 '10 at 9:43.

1. `target.Rows(rowNr + 1).Insert`: 1.1. does not extend the Named Range by one Row (AFAIK the only way to do so implicitly via Insert Row (vs. explicitly modifying Range definition) and to do so *after* specified Row # is via Row #'s 1 to Count - 1) and 1.2) only shifts Columns in the `target` Range down by one Row.  In many (and probably most) cases, Columns to the right and/or left of the `target` Range need to be shifted down as well.
2. `target.Rows(rowNr).Copy target.Rows(rowNr + 1)` does not copy
   the Formats which are often if not usually desired also.

Private Sub InsertNewRowInRange( _
   TargetRange As Range, _
   Optional InsertAfterRowNumber As Integer = -1, _
   Optional InsertEntireSheetRow As Boolean = True)

```
' -- InsertAfterRowNumber must be 1 to TargetRange.Rows.Count - 1 for TargetRange to be extended by one Row and for there to be
' --    Formats and Formulas to copy from (e.g. can't be 0).  Default: If -1, defaults to TargetRange.Rows.Count.
' --    Recommend dummy spacer Row at the bottom of TargetRange which, btw, would also be necessary to manually extend a Range
' --    by one Row implicitly via Insert Row (vs. explicilty via changing Range definition).

        If InsertAfterRowNumber = -1 Then
            InsertAfterRowNumber = TargetRange.Rows.Count
        End If

        If InsertEntireSheetRow Then
            TargetRange.Cells(InsertAfterRowNumber + 1, 1).Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Insert
        Else
            TargetRange.Rows(InsertAfterRowNumber + 1).Insert
        End If

        TargetRange.Rows(InsertAfterRowNumber).Select
        Selection.Copy

        TargetRange.Rows(InsertAfterRowNumber + 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlPasteFormats, _
            Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, _
            Transpose:=False
        Selection.PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, _
            Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, _
            Transpose:=False

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End Sub
```

Comment: I have used this code. It meets my requirement and worked like a charm. But suddenly I started getting **Run-time error '1004'. Insert method of Range class failed.** at the line `TargetRange.Rows(InsertAfterRowNumber + 1).Insert`. It worked for some days and then suddenly I started getting this error.

Comment: @JDoshi: Just saw this.  What is the current definition of TargetRange and what are the Parameters you passed?

Comment: Actually my sheet was protected which cause me the issue. Unprotecting it did the work for me. Thanks anyways for the great solution.

Comment: @JDoshi: You're welcome!  Btw, you can also thank me by Up Voting my Answer if you haven't already.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution building on answer from @Tom. It does not use "Selection", and it's possible to insert multiple rows.

```
' Appends one or more rows to a range.
' You can choose if you want to keep formulas and if you want to insert entire sheet rows.
Private Sub expand_range( _
                        target_range As Range, _
                        Optional num_rows As Integer = 1, _
                        Optional insert_entire_sheet_row As Boolean = False, _
                        Optional keep_formulas As Boolean = False _
                        )

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo Cleanup

    Dim original_cell As Range: Set original_cell = ActiveCell
    Dim last_row As Range: Set last_row = target_range.Rows(target_range.Rows.Count)

    ' Insert new row(s) above the last row and copy contents from last row to the new one(s)
    IIf(insert_entire_sheet_row, last_row.Cells(1).EntireRow, last_row) _
        .Resize(num_rows).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
    last_row.Copy
    last_row.Offset(-num_rows).PasteSpecial
    last_row.ClearContents

    On Error Resume Next ' This will fail if there are no formulas and keep_formulas = True
        If keep_formulas Then
            With last_row.Offset(-num_rows).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
                .Copy
                .Offset(1).Resize(num_rows).PasteSpecial
            End With
        End If
    On Error GoTo Cleanup

Cleanup:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    original_cell.Select
    If Err Then Err.Raise Err.Number, , Err.Description
End Sub
```