# How to insert a new row at the top or bottom of a named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named range set up on a sheet. It is called ProjData.
My VB code can insert a new row alphabetically ok.
Where I am stuck is adding the new row at the top of the named range or at the bottom of the named range.
I have tried many iterations on the range.insert, but I cannot add the rows at the top or the bottom. The row always inserts on the sheet row before or after the named range.

Here is my code.

```
Public Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim aNumber As Variant
Dim rowNum As Variant
Dim iRows As Integer

aNumber = "Orange"

Set rng = Worksheets("Overview").Range("ProjData")

iRows = rng.Rows.Count
If iRows = 1 And rng(1, 1).Value = "" Then
    'rng.Rows(rowNum).Insert shift:=xlDown
    'rng.Rows(rowNum).Copy rng.Rows(rowNum + 1)
    rng(1, 1).Value = aNumber
    For x = 2 To 19
            rng(1, x).Formula = "=now()"
        Next x
    Exit Sub
End If

rowNum = Application.Match(aNumber, rng.Columns(1), 1)

If Not IsError(rowNum) Then
    rng.Rows(rowNum + 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
    rng.Rows(rowNum).Copy rng.Rows(rowNum + 1)
    rng(rowNum + 1, 1).Value = aNumber
Else
    rng.Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlDown

    rng.Rows(2).Copy rng.Rows(1)
    rng(1, 1).Value = aNumber

End If
```

End Sub

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: so you want it `inside the named range` as the new first row of the named range?

Comment: You may like to refer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616355/excel-vba-how-to-insert-a-new-row-into-a-range-and-copy-formulas> a similar question.

Comment: Hi, Scott. Yes, the new row needs to be in the named range, whether it is added at the top, or the bottom.  Inserting rows within the named range works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had to solve a similar problem myself. Like you I found that inserting a new row between two existing rows in the range worked fine, but inserting the row above the first row of the range and inserting the row below the bottom row of the range didn't change the size of the range to include them.

Based on [a relevant answer on the MrExcel.com forums](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/add-row-at-end-of-named-range.686422/), in order to include the new row in the range it appears that you need to:

- Create a copy of the original range
- Resize the new range, using it's
  Offset and Resize methods, to include the new row
- Assign the original
  range's name to the new range

I've written two functions based on this logic to add rows to the start or the end of a range. Please read through the comments for how I've applied the logic and I hope the code is of use.

```
Function InsertRowAtStartOfNamedRange(sheet As Worksheet, rangeName As String) As Integer
    Dim firstRowOfRange As Range, newRow As Range, workingRange As Range
    
    With sheet.Range(rangeName)
        ' Get the first row of the named range.
        Set firstRowOfRange = .Rows(1).EntireRow
        ' Insert the new row above the first row of the named range.
        firstRowOfRange.Insert xlShiftDown
        ' Set the new row range so we can return the row number from this function.
        Set newRow = firstRowOfRange.Offset(rowOffset:=-1)
        ' Assign a copy of the offset and resized range to workingRange.
        Set workingRange = .Offset(rowOffset:=-1)
        Set workingRange = workingRange.Resize(rowSize:=.Rows.Count + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Change the named range to use workingRange's resized range by assigning the range name.
    workingRange.Name = rangeName
    
    ' Return the row number from the function.
    InsertRowAtStartOfNamedRange = newRow.Row
    
End Function


Function InsertRowAtEndOfNamedRange(sheet As Worksheet, rangeName As String) As Integer
    Dim lastRowOfRange As Range, newRow As Range, workingRange As Range
    
    With sheet.Range(rangeName)
        ' Get the last row of the named range.
        Set lastRowOfRange = .Rows(rowIndex:=.Rows.Count).EntireRow
        ' Insert the new row from the row below the last row of the named range.
        lastRowOfRange.Offset(rowOffset:=1).Insert xlShiftDown
        ' Set the new row range so we can return the row number from this function.
        Set newRow = lastRowOfRange.Offset(rowOffset:=1)
        ' Assign a copy of the resized range to workingRange.
        Set workingRange = .Resize(rowSize:=.Rows.Count + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Change the named range to use workingRange's resized range by assigning the range name.
    workingRange.Name = rangeName
    
    ' Return the row number from the function.
    InsertRowAtEndOfNamedRange = newRow.Row
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will add a new Row before the specified row of a Named Range, and then Resize the Named Range to include the newly inserted row

(e.g. if your Named Range is `$A$4:$B$17`, then `$A$4:$B$4` is Row 1, and `$A$17:$B$17` is Row 14, or Row 15 to add a Row to the End of the Named Range)

```
Public Function NamedRange_AddRow(Target As Name, InsertAt As Long) As Boolean
    'Target: Named Range to insert Row to.
    'InsertAt: Row of the Named Range to insert the Row before;
    '    If this is 1 larger than the count of Rows, the new row will be added to the end
    NamedRange_AddRow = False
    On Error GoTo ExitFunction
    
    Dim InsertRange As Range, CurrentRows As Long
    
    CurrentRows = Target.RefersToRange.Rows.Count
    
    If (InsertAt < 1) Or (InsertAt > (CurrentRows + 1)) Then Exit Function
    
    Target.RefersToRange.Rows(InsertAt).Offset(IIf(InsertAt > CurrentRows, 1, 0), 0).Insert xlShiftDown
    
    Target.RefersTo = Target.RefersToRange.Offset(IIf(InsertAt = 1, -1, 0), 0).Resize(CurrentRows + 1)
    
    NamedRange_AddRow = True
ExitFunction:
End Function
```